# footballdata package - FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: python, package

I know this particular question has been asked loads of times but I have searched through and tried multiple approaches to solve this all with the same issue still existing so unfortunately have to ask for help because I cannot solve myself.

I have the following package installed: https://github.com/skagr/footballdata

When trying to read_games I get the dreadful error message. After reading through some of the package it looks as though it should overwrite the data if it already exists but I think this is more of a windows error.

Any help will be appreciated.

I have tried creating a parent structure in the folders but the same error exists. Also tried using Pathlib to say if folder exists=OK but still doesnt solve the error.

edit: Code added.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import unidecode
import footballdata as foo
import pathlib
pathlib.Path('C:\\Users\\username\\.spyder-py3\\data').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)


EPL = foo.MatchHistory('ENG-Premier League', [22]).read_games()
print(EPL.head())
```

As you can see there isnt much to it but getting the error stops anything getting past this point.

thanks

Comment: How do you expect us to help without showing us your code?

Comment: @JohnGordon - sorry, i have added this now.